# Ember.js wrapping all javascript objects on a page

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to use Ember.js for only part of a page in my Rails project. I'm using ember-rails but am running into problems with my other javascript objects on the page (specifically Google Maps) because Ember automatically wraps them.

Is there a way to prevent this? My Ember code is namespaced but it seems requiring Ember in application.js.coffee causes Ember to wrap any javascript object.

My Ember application for the page is initialized as following:

```
(($) ->
  namespace 'AT.Ember.Activity', (exports) ->
   exports.init = () ->
       App = Ember.Application.create()
       # Implementation
) jQuery
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember doesn't wrap your javascript objects. Coffeescript does, maybe that's what's going on?